# How to Check if seek API is available on your Android Device?

Tags: java, android

Do you know how to check if the android device `Secure element evaluation kit API` is available through code in android? thanks in advance.

Comment: and by seek you mean Secure element evaluation kit?

Comment: @njzk2 yes. seek - Secure element evaluation kit

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for asking. i already updated my question to make it clear.

Comment: You can check if class is available: try { Class.forName("my.ClassName"); // It is available } catch (ClassNotFoundException exception) { // It is not available }

Answer (score 0):

You can connect using adb and check  the existence of this file

org.simalliance.openmobileapi.jar in system/framework

if this file exist that's mean you have the lib seek in your android device.

Hope it's help